# What is the best way to reset Ninject's IKernel container in an MVC app?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-2, dependency-injection, ninject, ninject-2

Basically in my `Global.asax` code I have the following `IKernel` property for Ninject setup like this (Also taking advantage of Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation).  This Container is automatically called upon once it seems on the `CreateKernel()` override:

```
protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
        {
            return Container;
        }
```

and my container property:

```
static IKernel _container;
        public static IKernel Container
        {
            get
            {
                if (_container == null)
                {
                    _container = new StandardKernel();
                    _container.Load(new SiteModule(_container));
                    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => _container.Get<IServiceLocator>());
                }
                return _container;
            }
        }
```

As you can see I am loading simply one module defining a list of my interface<->service bindings, which shouldn't be important to this problem however, but my problem being - no matter how hard I seem to try, I cannot get my _`container` null again once it has been initially instantiated when I restart my MVC website.  From editing and re-saving the Web.config file (good old trick) through to flushing the app pool or even restarting IIS(!), my container *apparently* still exists. I really don't understand how this can be the case.  I know on my initial loads `_container` is null and `SiteModule` does load correctly.

This is a problem of course because I now wish to add some new bindings for newly created services and the container is never returning to null :P

FYI. Even moving my breakpoint into the container null test doesn't appear to get this going, don't ask me how this doesn't fix the issue, but I know the inside of that if should be valid, because on initial load there are no errors, everything maps up fine.

Thanks guys, if you feel you need to see `SiteModule()` let me know and I can extend this post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried restarting your web server?  I realize this might not be an option in production, but it should get you through the development phase (if it works).

Comment: Well as I said I tried restarting IIS, I didn't try restarting the entire server =)

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, `CreateKernel()` is only called once during `Application_Start()` ([view source](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.web.mvc/blob/master/mvc2/src/Ninject.Web.Mvc/NinjectHttpApplication.cs#L44)) so, unless you are using `Container` elsewhere, is there any benefit to caching it?

Have you tried something like this?

```
protected override IKernel CreateKernel()
{
    IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();

    // Do your Load() and ServiceLocator stuff here

    return kernel;
}
```

For reference, the Ninject website's [implementation](http://github.com/ninject/ninject.website/blob/master/src/Ninject.Website/NinjectWebsiteApplication.cs#L38-L45).